# In php, how to call a certain function

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new in using xampp. i made a grade database for a school but i got stuck on one part of m database. my class table. the class table is holding most of the primary key of other tables.

for example:

> class table holds
>   class_id(pk)
>   subject_id(fk of the subjects table)
>   student_no(fk of the students table)
>   profess_id(fk of the professors table)
>   grade
>   sem
>   academic_year

i've done the database and fixed their relation. when i get to the php part is where i have a problem.

when i try to call the datas on the class table i can only print the id/nos of the foreign key but i don't want to that to happen. lets say, instead of seeing `student_no = 1`, i want it to display the student name. logical speaking it's possible but frankly i don't know the codes in php to call the name of the student through there student_no. i need help for that code please. just a noob.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: Unless you have 1:1 tuition, there's a redundancy here. In fact, there's a whole level of design missing here.

Comment: @maling please refer below links 1) http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm 2) http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php.htm

Comment: which code andrewsi? the code in php format?

Comment: i will practice my php skills. thanks for the info Roopendra.

Answer (score 0):

Inform you about JOINS in SQL so you can concat your tables and pull the data out you want.

Comment: i know about joins in mysql but i don't know how to get them into php. what would i put into my mysql_connect for that to show in php

Comment: Don't use `mysql_connect` (it's deprecated) use `mysqli_connect()` instead. You don't have to change anything in your connection call. You have to execute statements with your SQL code in it.